# How we add the Subclass Xib in the Main class Xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, subclass

I am working on application for Ipad.in this application i have a UIButton on my first class Xib ,Now i want to add second class XIB in this first Class XIB on Button click.i know  the how to  call second class XIB.which is just like this..

```
-(IBAction)displaysecondclass
{
 secondview *sec=[[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
 [sec release];
}
```

But i not want to go secondclass ,i need to display second class XIB on firstview just like this.

```
-(IBAction)displaysecondclass
{
 secondview *sec=[[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubView:sec];
}
```

can any one help me how to add second class xib in first view.thanx in advance.

Comment: uh..huh? Your code already adds the `second class` view to whatever `self` is, assuming `first view`. Not sure I understand you..

Comment: are u sure secondview class xib file name as secondview?

Comment: @skram i not want just like this..i add second class in first view.

Comment: sorry :\ I don't understand at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the button code to

```
-(IBAction)displaysecondclass
{
 secondview *sec=[[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubView:sec.view];
}
```

Please note that you will need to add additional functions to release the viewcontroller once you dont need it anymore

Comment: sorry but I am little confused.This method will add new view on existing view, right?Or it will replace the first xib from and add new one?and what about first xib, i mean will it will get deallocated?

Comment: it will add the secondview as a child of your current view, it will not replace it :)

Comment: But according to question, he wants to replace do not want to add.

Comment: @NuzhatZari he says i want to add where did you read replace?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I misunderstood the question, thanks.and Is it possible to replace?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith thanx for answer but i need to add secondview as child view of firstview .can u please share some link or tutorial about subclass or child class adding in parentview.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for everyone actually i am working as part time IOS programmer.All though its was not difficult task That i mention in my quesiton.i was little bit confuse when i ask this question whether it is related about Subclass or newclass,thats why i post Question.Thanx for every one to help me.now i got its solution using this link may be it help to Some one new commer.

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iPhone-Create-SubView.html